# Why repositories have to be redeclared in a project implementing a project-dependency?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Let's say we have a **Gradle** project with the following structure:

```
.
├── a
│   
└── b
```

```kotlin
// a build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "org.example.a"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://some-external-repo.com")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.externaldependency:1.0.1")
}
```

```kotlin
// b build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "org.example.b"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":a"))
}
```

For some unknown reason, Gradle requires all repositories declared in `a`, to also be present in `b`.

Without doing so, we'll get the following error, when syncing in **IntelliJ Idea**:

```
Could not find com.externaldependency:1.0.1.
Required by:
    project :b > project :a

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

However, **build** works just fine.

Why it works this way? It's kind of breaks **encapsulation** between projects.

Comment: Does `./gradlew build` work from a command line? For me, the command line build also fails. Can you provide a sample project if it behaves differently for you?

Comment: @Andrey Yes, command line build works. An example project: https://github.com/Gieted/test

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `repositories` blocks from your `a` and `b` modules.
2. Declare [`dependencyResolutionManagement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) in your `settings.gradle.kts`:

   ```kotlin
   rootProject.name = "test"

   include("a")
   include("b")

   dependencyResolutionManagement {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
           maven(url = "https://some-external-repo.com")
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This answer is not really helpful. I know you could do that, but it's effectively the same as just adding the repository to all subprojects. What I've asked, is why you have to declare a repository for "com.externaldependency:1.0.1" in project b in the first place. It's a's dependency, that has nothing to do with b, so why it results in an error?